# detecting distance of scrolling in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Is there a way to detect the amount of distance a scrolling movement takes place in a listView.

i am trying to implement a custom view container that takes two views in a vertical linearLayout or FrameLayout(still undecided) and simple manually gradually move/animate the two child views merging together/overlapping(like a parallex effect).

Once both child views are on screen i want to begin to track the movement of the scrolling inside the listview and gradually move the two child view objects together and stop moving them together at a certain point.

i could only find this example that only just detects that it is scrolling up or down but it doesnt specificy the amount of scrolling/distance that has occured.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(mLastFirstVisibleItem<firstVisibleItem)
            {
                Log.i("SCROLLING DOWN","TRUE");
            }
            if(mLastFirstVisibleItem>firstVisibleItem)
            {
                Log.i("SCROLLING UP","TRUE");
            }
            mLastFirstVisibleItem=firstVisibleItem;

        }
    });
```

Is there no interface callback such like this as an example:

```
public void onScrolling(int movementY){ //movementY value represents how much u have scrolled from the point of touching the listview and applying the scroll motion}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does your custom ViewGroup have to do with a ListView?

Comment: the manual transtion animation occurs for each item in the listview and i need callbacks from the listview to know about the scrolling in order to gradually merge the two child views inside a single listview Item

Comment: if your each item has the same height you can use OnScrollListener for that,  if not,  you cannot do anything

Comment: why does it have to be the same height? a ListView can inflate any view and in my case i will inflate a item layout that uses this custom viewgroup that takes two child views that is alligned vertically with a spacing inbetween that gets filled once the two child views merge together while scrolling

Comment: the only listener you can use is OnScrollListener, with fixed height you can compute the scroll offset,  otherwise you simply cannot

Comment: Can i detect GestureDectors on a listView?

Comment: yes,  but imho you will not get any help from it, you can try though

Answer (score 2):

See [this one](https://gist.github.com/mariotaku/1f6c31691fc2ed4ce514). It does exactly what you want.

```
/**
 * Created by mariotaku on 14/10/22.
 */
public class ListScrollDistanceCalculator implements OnScrollListener {

    private ScrollDistanceListener mScrollDistanceListener;

    private boolean mListScrollStarted;
    private int mFirstVisibleItem;
    private int mFirstVisibleHeight;
    private int mFirstVisibleTop, mFirstVisibleBottom;
    private int mTotalScrollDistance;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (view.getCount() == 0) return;
        switch (scrollState) {
            case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE: {
                mListScrollStarted = false;
                break;
            }
            case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL: {
                final View firstChild = view.getChildAt(0);
                mFirstVisibleItem = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                mFirstVisibleTop = firstChild.getTop();
                mFirstVisibleBottom = firstChild.getBottom();
                mFirstVisibleHeight = firstChild.getHeight();
                mListScrollStarted = true;
                mTotalScrollDistance = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getTotalScrollDistance() {
        return mTotalScrollDistance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (totalItemCount == 0 || !mListScrollStarted) return;
        final View firstChild = view.getChildAt(0);
        final int firstVisibleTop = firstChild.getTop(), firstVisibleBottom = firstChild.getBottom();
        final int firstVisibleHeight = firstChild.getHeight();
        final int delta;
        if (firstVisibleItem > mFirstVisibleItem) {
            mFirstVisibleTop += mFirstVisibleHeight;
            delta = firstVisibleTop - mFirstVisibleTop;
        } else if (firstVisibleItem < mFirstVisibleItem) {
            mFirstVisibleBottom -= mFirstVisibleHeight;
            delta = firstVisibleBottom - mFirstVisibleBottom;
        } else {
            delta = firstVisibleBottom - mFirstVisibleBottom;
        }
        mTotalScrollDistance += delta;
        if (mScrollDistanceListener != null) {
            mScrollDistanceListener.onScrollDistanceChanged(delta, mTotalScrollDistance);
        }
        mFirstVisibleTop = firstVisibleTop;
        mFirstVisibleBottom = firstVisibleBottom;
        mFirstVisibleHeight = firstVisibleHeight;
        mFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    }

    public void setScrollDistanceListener(ScrollDistanceListener listener) {
        mScrollDistanceListener = listener;
    }

    public static interface ScrollDistanceListener {
        void onScrollDistanceChanged(int delta, int total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bug : onScroll will be call mang time in one move event and mTotalScrollDistance is not correct.